# Input gets deleted/overwritten after changing to different Admin Menu

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, themes

After I have added a plugin menu and have some input to be saved in the database, everything works fine and gets saved, even if I refresh the current page. However, once I go to other menus in Wordpress admin and come back to my plugin menu, my inputs get deleted. What causes this issue?

**Functions.php** 
Adding the item to menu

```
function plugin_admin_exist() {
    add_menu_page('plugin', 'plugin', 'manage_options', 'plugin', 'plugin_Dashboard', plugins_url( 'plugin/images/icon.png' ));
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'plugin_admin_exist');
```

**Menu Function:** 
 External .php file for my html tags and php scripts.

```
function admin_Dashboard() {ob_start();
    require ( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'dashboard.php'); }
```

**Database Set-up** 
Create database related to my input fields.

```
if (get_option('Plugin_Master_Run')) {
    $AdminOption = get_option('Plugin_Master_Run');
} else {
    add_option('Plugin_Master_Run', array(
        'plugin_profile'       => '', 
        'plugin_googleFont'    => '', 
        'plugin_browserIcon'   => '',
        'plugin_regularMobile' => '',
        'plugin_retinaMobile'  => '',
        'plugin_logo'          => '',
        'plugin_retinaLogo'    => ''
    ));
}
```

**Input in external page for menu option:** 
 I have already declared `$AdminOption` as global variable and included a new array with `htmlentities($_POST['plugin_profile'], ENT_QUOTES),` for `update_option('Plugin_Master_Run', $newAdminValue);` and get the new input by `$AdminOption = $newAdminValue;`

```
<input name="Admin_profile" value="<?php echo $AdminOption['plugin_profile']; ?>" type="text"/>
```

Comment: I tink that you should take a look to [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) and build the settings page of your plugin using it.

Comment: @cybmeta but How come when i enter text in input and click saved, it get stored? i have even checked the phpmyadmin and it look like the input values are there. but once i go to another page and come back to the plugin it get deleted and overwrite in database.

Comment: Show us the full code you refer as `htmlentities($_POST['plugin_profile'], ENT_QUOTES)` and `update_option('Plugin_Master_Run', $newAdminValue);`. I think that you are executing that code in every page, so `$_POST['plugin_profile']` is empty if you are not in your options page. Anyway, I recommend again to use the Settings API for your purpose (build a page in the backend to manage options).

Comment: @cybmeta i thing imma look more into Setting API (sound promising ), now, will that allow me to pull from database to theme? after input saved.

Comment: Oh, yes. The settings API is used to build the settings page in the backend. Once a option is saved, you can use [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) to get the value in a theme, plugin or anywhere within Wordpress.

Comment: I see, it sound nice, but can i style the options?

Comment: You can apply CSS to any admin page, so yes, you can style the options if thay what you asking.

Comment: @cybmeta i see, thank you so much, i been watching video on setting API, it sound like thats even the right way of doing it. Please answer so i can mark u for check.